# pipelight Libraries: FAILURE

Tags: pipelight

I installed pipelight and then executed this:

```
pipelight-plugin --system-check
```

The last lines of the output were:

```
libXrender.so.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1
libxslt.so.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1
libXxf86vm.so.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1
Libraries: FAILURE
```

Where do I find an explanation or a log? Whats the next step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all of these libraries are necessary to use the plugins supported by Pipelight. You can find a list of really essential libraries at http://pipelight.net/cms/faqs/faq-libraries-missing.html

Some libraries are only required for very specific use cases like libnetapi.so which makes it possible for Wine to interact with Windows servers and Windows network shares. This is not used by any of the supported plugins and you do not need to care about it. There was also a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/pipelight/+bug/1327518 to fix these remaining libraries and most of them should be fixed in the next release (except libnetapi.so which is not multiarch ready on Ubuntu yet).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are after a certain end-result.  But I ran through a lot of problems with pipelight and in the end I was able to run:

```
wine-browser --no-pipelight --windowed
```

this runs firefox within wine, which seems to work fine.